# Fill missing values based unique IDs from another column

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a data frame with User ID and a Device Model values

The User ID is unique for each user however there are duplicates for multiple logins and there are no missing values
Device Model has missing value

I need to address the same device model for users that has the same User ID. Like This:

```
    Device Model        User ID

0   iPhone 11   1590761773215-7300441
1   iPhone XR   1590761549649-1399336
2   NAN         1590761549649-1399336
3   iPhone 7    1589030810407-6386535
4   NAN         1590761773215-7300441


    Device Model        User ID

0   iPhone 11   1590761773215-7300441
1   iPhone XR   1590761549649-1399336
2   iPhone XR   1590761549649-1399336
3   iPhone 7    1589030810407-6386535
4   iPhone 11   1590761773215-7300441
```

Does anybody knows how to solve this? I tried to use join (below) but it didn`t work and I don`t know any other solution for this

```
join_df_device = pd.merge(device_model_df,device_type_nonull,on ='Device Model',how ='left')
```

join_df_device

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood,

Use `df.groupby` to group all similar `User ID` and use `df.fillna`

```
df['Device_Model'] = df.groupby('User_ID')['Device_Model'].ffill().bfill()

    Device_Model        User_ID
0   iPhone 11   1590761773215-7300441
1   iPhone XR   1590761549649-1399336
2   iPhone XR   1590761549649-1399336
3   iPhone 7    1589030810407-6386535
4   iPhone 11   1590761773215-7300441
```

Answer (score 1):

Although [Ch3steR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62106520/3944322) is easier in this case, here's a solution with merging as you tried:

```
df[['User ID']].merge(df.dropna().drop_duplicates(), on='User ID')
```

Result:

```
                 User ID Device Model
0  1590761773215-7300441    iPhone 11
1  1590761773215-7300441    iPhone 11
2  1590761549649-1399336    iPhone XR
3  1590761549649-1399336    iPhone XR
4  1589030810407-6386535     iPhone 7
```

Comment: Yes, Agreed. Nice answer +1 ;)

Comment: @Ch3steR: but yours is more elegant, therefore +1 too ;)

Comment: But doesn't solve OP's question so deleted my answer.

Comment: @Ch3steR: I'd restore it

Comment: If it will be useful I'll restore it. Do you think it adds any value?

Comment: @Ch3steR: I think so, as it is the straightforward solution (I came up with it too, but you were faster). Just do the filling in both directions.

Comment: Restored it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the solution however it didn`t work for me :(. My dataset had 44K rows and and when I ran this code my final numbers 77K rows, not sure what I did wrong here...

Comment: This might occur if a) you have users with multiple, different devices in your dataframe or b) you have additional columns with different entries for one and the same user. In case of a) you can't unequivocally solve this problem. Can you check if either a) or b) is the case?